# Apple Mail not saving Smart Mailboxes

Tags: macos, mail.app, email

I'm having some trouble with Apple Mail 6.3 (1503) and Smart Mailboxes under 10.8.3. When I create Smart Mailboxes they work just as one would expect them to. When I quit Mail and re-open it, they're gone as if I would have never created them. I found a similar issue with an earlier version of Mac OS X where deleting the `SmartMailboxesSomething.plist` in `~/Library/Mail/` fixed the problem. This does not seem to apply for OS X's current version anymore.

I filed a bug about this: http://openradar.appspot.com/13700673

This happens on both my MacBook Air and my iMac. Both are running OS X's latest version.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks!
— Flo

Comment: Sorry, I tired but can not replicate our problem.

Comment: FYI--I use gmail in mail.

Comment: I use three Gmail accounts and one different as well. I think it's some kind of permissions error. Maybe Mail can't write to the file that stores the Mailboxes. I did already repair my disk permissions, but that didn't help.

Comment: Not that it should matter, but since there are multiple ways, how do you create them.

Comment: I create them using the + button in the lower left corner of the Mailbox list view.

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear. Could you show us what "arguments"  are you using when setting new smart folder. A screen shot would be nice.

Comment: Oh, sure. I have tried it with three different ones. One that fetches all unread objects (over all mailboxes and even in my spam folders, etc.) and two more that fetch all red and blue flagged mails. Pretty simple, only one argument. The rules apply if all sub-rules match and the both checkboxes are not checked.

Comment: OK; I am sorry, but I can not recreate your problem with the information provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I filed a radar (rdar://13700673) with Apple and after a few mails back and forth they figured out how to solve the problem:

```
chmod -a 'everyone deny write,delete,append,writeattr,writeextattr,chown' ~/Library/Mobile\ Documents/com~apple~mail/Data/MailData/* ~/Library/Mobile\ Documents/com~apple~mail/Data/MailData/Signatures/*
```

Looks like I had some permission issues on that files.

Answer (score 0):

I would troubleshoot by quitting Mail, moving all Mail app preferences to desktop, and restarting Mail.

Comment: Can you please add the list of all Mail preferences which would require copying? And maybe explain how this would differ from the things the OP already tried (unsuccessfully).